# specifying columns in PySpark loop

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, outliers

Thanks for reading. I'm looking to implement a solution in which I can flag outliers in specified columns by getting the 25th and 75th percentile values. The reason I want to flag them (such as with 0s and 1s in new columns) is so I can later see those outliers via longitude/latitude. Part of the data frame looks like this:

```
+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+
|ID         |cl_Left_yCm|cl_Right_xCm|cl_Right_yCm|
+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+
|a1          |132        |0           |-153       |
|a1          |132        |0           |-153       |
|a1          |129        |0           |-153       |
|a1          |129        |0           |-153       |
|a2          |129        |0           |-152       |
|a2          |129        |0           |-152       |
|a2          |130        |0           |-152       |
|a2          |130        |0           |-152       |
|a2          |130        |0           |-152       |
|a3          |134        |0           |-147       |
+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+
```

We're only interested in flagging outliers for the integer columns, such as "cl_Left_yCm", etc. Here's the code I tried to run:

```
bounds = {
    c: dict(
        zip(["q1", "q3"], df.approxQuantile(c, [0.25, 0.75], 0))
    )
    for c in df(df['cl_Left_yCm','cl_Right_yCm'])
}
```

Unfortunately it shoots **Error:
An error was encountered:
'DataFrame' object is not callable**.
Is there a problem in the way I'm calling the columns? I'm fairly new to PySpark and fear I'm missing something obvious, so any alternatives to the solution or guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly supply the column names as a list rather than indexing them through `df` -

As the earlier code snippet - `df(df['cl_Left_yCm','cl_Right_yCm'])` returns a `DataFrame` object which `approxQuantile` does not accept as an argument

## Data Preparation

```
input_str = """
|a1          |132        |0           |-153
|a1          |132        |0           |-153
|a1          |129        |0           |-153
|a1          |129        |0           |-153
|a2          |129        |0           |-152
|a2          |129        |0           |-152
|a2          |130        |0           |-152
|a2          |130        |0           |-152
|a2          |130        |0           |-152
|a3          |134        |0           |-147
""".split("|")

input_values = list(map(lambda x: x.strip() if x != '' else None,input_str[1:]))

n = len(input_values)

input_list = [tuple(input_values[i:i+4]) for i in range(0,n,4)]

sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame(input_list,['ID','cl_Left_yCm','cl_Right_xCm','cl_Right_yCm'])

to_convert = set(['cl_Left_yCm','cl_Right_xCm','cl_Right_yCm'])

sparkDF = reduce(
    lambda df, x: df.withColumn(x, F.col(x).cast(DoubleType())),
    to_convert,
    sparkDF,
)

sparkDF.show()

+---+-----------+------------+------------+
| ID|cl_Left_yCm|cl_Right_xCm|cl_Right_yCm|
+---+-----------+------------+------------+
| a1|      132.0|         0.0|      -153.0|
| a1|      132.0|         0.0|      -153.0|
| a1|      129.0|         0.0|      -153.0|
| a1|      129.0|         0.0|      -153.0|
| a2|      129.0|         0.0|      -152.0|
| a2|      129.0|         0.0|      -152.0|
| a2|      130.0|         0.0|      -152.0|
| a2|      130.0|         0.0|      -152.0|
| a2|      130.0|         0.0|      -152.0|
| a3|      134.0|         0.0|      -147.0|
+---+-----------+------------+------------+
```

## Bounds

```
bounds = {
    c: dict(
        zip(["q1", "q3"], sparkDF.approxQuantile(c, [0.25, 0.75], 0))
    )
    for c in ['cl_Left_yCm','cl_Right_yCm']
}

bounds

{'cl_Left_yCm': {'q1': 129.0, 'q3': 132.0},
 'cl_Right_yCm': {'q1': -153.0, 'q3': -152.0}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have a tiny bug for the error you're getting

```
    for c in df(df['cl_Left_yCm','cl_Right_yCm']) # <------
}
```

You're calling df like a function when it's an DataFrame object.

To access the columns you want , you should be able to do it with just `df[['cl_Left_yCm','cl_Right_yCm']]`; but approxQuantile needs column names, so the code should be more like

```
bounds = {
    c: dict(
        zip(["q1", "q3"], df.approxQuantile(c, [0.25, 0.75], 0))
    )
    for c in ['cl_Left_yCm','cl_Right_yCm']
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your response. That did solve the previous error, but it's now throwing a new one--"**An error was encountered: col should be a string, list or tuple, but got <class 'pyspark.sql.column.Column'>**"--
Any ideas what this might mean? The docs are very unclear on this. Many thanks again.

Comment: Per other people's answers, approximateQuantiles needs `col` to be column names instead of the actual columns.

Answer (score 0):

`pyspark.sql.DataFrame.approxQuantile` needs the first argument to be either a string, list or tuple, [see here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.approxQuantile.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.approxQuantile). In your code, beside syntax errors, it seems that you want to provide a column object instead.

You should simply iterate through the list of column names like this

```
bounds = {
    c: dict(
        zip(["q1", "q3"], df.approxQuantile(c, [0.25, 0.75], 0))
    )
    for c in ['cl_Left_yCm','cl_Right_yCm']
}
```